# How to compare ImageView ids on click event?

Tags: java, android, arrays, for-loop, equals

I have a set of ImageView in which some of them are red colored blink for some time like below.

[image]

[image]

I want to do that ,When I'm click on colored blinked imageViews it change as tic mark and when I'm click non blinked imageViews it change as cross mark.

**My issue is my current code only tic the one imageview and all other imageViews are cross marked.**

So how to make tic mark more than one ImageView.

Here is my code:

```
  org_id = new int[]{R.id.img1_1, R.id.img1_2, R.id.img1_3, R.id.img1_4};

        all = new int[]{R.id.img1_1, R.id.img1_2, R.id.img1_3, R.id.img1_4};




        Random random = new Random();
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++) {
            id = all[random.nextInt(all.length)];


            ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(findViewById(id), "backgroundResource", R.drawable.new_stateimg, R.drawable.org_state).setDuration(2000);
            Toast.makeText(Game.this, "index" + findViewById(id), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            animator.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
            animator.start();

        for (int i=0; i < org_id.length; ++i) {
            final int btn = org_id[i];

            findViewById(btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if ((findViewById(id)).equals(findViewById(btn)))
                    {
                        findViewById(id).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.correct);

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(Game.this, "wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        findViewById(btn).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cross);

                    }

                }
            });
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare your id like

```
    if (id.getId() == btn.getId())
```

Do it in your code.

```
     public void onClick(View view) {
             ImageView imgView = (ImageView)view; //edited
             if(imgView.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals
        (getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.correct).getConstantState()))
             imgView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.incorrect);//set here you incorrect image which you want.

            else 
                imgView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.correct);//set here your correct image

  }
```

Comment: @Neo Now see my updated answer and please read comment proper otherwise it will give more error.

Comment: v is already in scope and when change v to v1 or something else it arise NullPointerException.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139373/discussion-between-neo-and-dharmbir-singh).